# imageview not loading the image.app is shutting down

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageview and button in the xml file . loading the image1 and play song1.mp3 file.when the song is over it should load next image and play the song2.mp3 song it should go on until the last image. button for closing and exit the application.

```
      import android.media.MediaPlayer;
      import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.widget.ImageView;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MediaPlayer mpp;
    final int image[] = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.ball,R.drawable.cat};
    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


    String audio[]={"song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3"};


    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
            try {
                descriptor = getAssets().openFd(audio[i]);
                mpp.setDataSource( descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength());
                descriptor.close();
                mpp.prepare();
                mpp.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mpp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    img.setImageResource(image[i]);
                    i++;
                    mpp.start();
                }
            });
} }
```

Fatal Exception in main.RuntimeException not able to start the activity

Comment: What about a stack trace(Logcat)?

Comment: Give us the full stack trace